# Google Maps SVG marker with PNG fallback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg

I've implemented the following code for a Google map with a custom SVG marker:

```
function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var iconBase = 'http://localhost:8888/theme/wp-content/themes/bananas/images/';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map,
        icon        : iconBase + 'marker.svg'
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )
    {
        // create info window
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content     : $marker.html()
        });

        // show info window when marker is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            infowindow.open( map, marker );

        });
    }

}
```

This works great, but I wondered if it's possible to add a PNG fallback for browsers that do not support SVG?

Maybe it's possible to display a div instead of an icon and then control the SVG detection with modernizr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but for anyone else who's pondering this: Sure you can! Create both svg and png icons in the same folder, and make the file extension into a variable, like so:

```
var imageType;
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
icon: '/your/folder/marker.' + imageType
```

This allows you to change file extension based on browser, like this:

```
if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) === true) { //IE
   imageType = 'png';
} else {
   imageType = 'svg';
}
```

And voila! Crisp vector icons for modern retina displays, and reliable raster icons for your grandmother running Windows 7. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Google Maps API would handle the fallback for you but,

You can handle it yourself using the `Modernizr.svg` function in the Modernizr plugin to check if the current browser support `svg`.

I have a [sample in jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cyhfn7vs/) and here is the [direct link.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/cyhfn7vs/show/light/)

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#cp_embed_lCEux

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, I'll try this next week. I assume I can replace the SVG shape you've drawn with an image, like so: `var image_svc = "http://localhost:8888/theme/wp-content/themes/bananas/images/marker.svg";`?

Comment: I am not quite sure about this. You should be able to do it, but I think I read it somewhere saying that google map can not read the svg image directly from an external file. So you might have to use some other way to first load your svg in the file as an object first. I haven't try this yet so I have no idea :)